# The correct way to manage CI/CD flow

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

My team develop a microservice application, written in Java, and deployed to a kubernetes cluster. Each microservice is managed in its own git repository. Upon pull request to master, a Jenkins build pipleline runs which builds the application into a Docker image, tags the docker image as `<PR-number>-<build-number>` and pushes it to ECR. Additionally, it tags the source branch with the same convention.

Then, when merging to master, another Jenkins pipeline runs, which reads the latest tag, and based on that promotes the Docker image and sets the version in the kubernetes manifests.

The problem with this flow is that it doesn't allow squash commits, something that we'd really like to do. The problem is that when you squash commit, you lose the path to the commit you've tagged in the build pipeline, and hence you don't know what Docker image tag to set in the kubernetes manifests.

Additionally, this workflow doesn't feel too straightforward.

Can someone offer a better workflow that will allow the use of squash commits?